# Invalid Engine ID error in SNMP v3 microchip with manage engine MIB browser

Tags: snmp

I'm getting error for "SNMPv3" of invalid engine ID? what causes this error usually?
     it perfectly works when i select no auth,no priv. but for other two options of auth,no priv and auth,priv it gives error of invalid engine id.

Answer (score -2):

ManageEngine MibBrowser supports auto-discovery of SnmpEngineID, EngineBoots and EngineTime from an Authoritative SNMP Engine.

If  user has enabled the "**Set EngineID For Adding V3 entry**" and entered  SNMPV3 user details with EngineID parameter, MibBrowser displays the message received from Agent.

> As per [RFC3414](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414#section-3.2), If the value of the msgAuthoritativeEngineID
> field in the securityParameters is unknown then:
>
> a) a non-authoritative SNMP engine that performs discovery may
> optionally create a new entry in its Local  Configuration Datastore
> (LCD) and continue processing;
>
> or
>
> b) the usmStatsUnknownEngineIDs counter is incremented, and an error
> indication (unknownEngineID) together with  the OID and value of the
> incremented counter are returned to the calling module.
>
> Note in the event that a zero-length or other illegally sized
> msgAuthoritativeEngineID is received,b) should be chosen to facilitate
> engineID discovery. Otherwise, the choice between a) and b) is an
> implementation issue.

If Authoritative SNMP Engine returns "**unKnownEngineID OID**"(.1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.4.0) with incremental counter value to manager. Then, Mibbrowser displays the "Invalid EngineID" error.

Regards,
ManageEngine